# Expo Universal Linking broken

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am pretty much stuck here and need some help. Here is everything I have done so far:

AASA:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "com.lucdabomb.Boodschappen",
                "paths": [ "/invite/*"]
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I validated my site through branch.io and everything seems right.

Expo app.json:

```
"associatedDomains": ["applinks:myapp.app", "applinks:www.myapp.app"]
```

I enabled Associated Domains and created a new Provisioning Profile. I don't see where it is going wrong and need some help.

After some research people suggested to uninstall, power cycle and install the app again but with no success..

Answer (score 0):

Researching through the Expo documentation, it seems like the problem is explained in this [paragraph](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/?redirected):

"While some of the properties defined in app.json can be applied at runtime, others require modifying native build configuration files. ***For ExpoKit projects, we only apply these settings once, at the time the native projects are generated (i.e. when you run expo eject)***. This means that for existing ExpoKit projects, changing certain properties in app.json will not have the desired effect. Instead, you must modify the corresponding native configuration files. In most cases, we've provided here a brief description of the files or settings that need to be changed, but you can also refer to the Apple and Android documentation for more information."

As a solution maybe you can try to regenerate the app for the ios.For more information on this Inconsistent behavior see [blog](https://blog.branch.io/notice-inconsistent-universal-link-behavior-on-ios-11-2/) post